Set cell value to NumberFormat formatting
I am converting some of my data using
Sheets("Data").Range("F:F").NumberFormat = "0.000000"
However, I'm not actually updating the value of the cell into this format, which causes an issue later in my process. Is there a way I can update the Value of the cell to the NumberFormat, overwriting the existing?

only if you save it as text and loop the range and use Range.Format()

@ScottCraner - How? I can't figure this out. I tried looping through cells, using say Range("F2").text which correctly stores the cell values as visible on screen, but when I code to put that text value back over the active cell, it keeps removing the trailing zeros.

Sheets("Data").Range("F:F").NumberFormat = "@" and then loop: Sheets("Data").Range("F2").Value = Format(Sheets("Data").Range("F2"),"0.000000") @BruceWayne

@Matt Reed, what you wrote is unclear. Write down what exactly you have in your cells and what you would like to have.

@MGonet My cell contains '79723.66' I use NumberFormat to to format the cell to '79723.660000' However the VALUE of that cell is still 79723.66. I would the like actual value of the cell (not just what is displayed) to be 79723.660000

You can't enter a cell value of 79723.660000 because Excel automatically drops the trailing zeros.   If you want 79723.660000 to be the value then the cell needs to be formatted as text.  Might be useful here to explain what actual need is here - what are you using these cells for that you have this requirement?

@TimWilliams I eventually copy my data into a new tab using TEXTJOIN to get my columns into a Pipe delimited format, that is then exported as a text file to a team that has requested 6 decimals worth of precision.

@ScottCraner This method works for what I need, thank you.

When you do the textjoin you can use TEXT() to do what you are doing with VBA and leave the underlying number:  =TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,TEXT(F:F,"0.000000"))

Eg in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/79171795/478884 you can add something like If c = 6 Then fld = Format(fld, "0.000000") immediately after fld = data(r, c)   Sub 6 for whatever value is relevant for your Col F, in case you data doesn't start from Col A.
